# How to show uploaded image in view page? I am new in yii, I am unable to fix this please help me

Tags: yii

## In myprofile.php

```
 <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request- >baseUrl.'/xampp/htdocs/myapp/images/'.$model- >image,"image",array("width"=>200,"hieght"=>200)); ?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Read this sscee.org

Comment: picture does not appear. its appear like broken image

Comment: I know 0 php, but maybe spaces in between '-' and '>' are causing problems

Comment: dude don't write `/xampp/htdocs/` try this - `CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request- >baseUrl.'/images/'.$model- >image,"image",array("width"=>200,"hieght"=>200));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image url is incorrect.

`Yii::app()->request- >baseUrl.'/xampp/htdocs/myapp/images/'.$model- >image`

should be change into:

`Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/'.$model->image`

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
 <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) .'/images/'.$model->image,'',array('width'=>230,'height'=>500)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` allready contains you app root directory so you don't need to use `xampp/htdocs/myapp` .

try to use this

```
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/'.$model->image,"image",array("width"=>200,"hieght"=>200)); ?>
```